# Map over array while preserving discriminated union type

Tags: typescript

I have an array:

```js
const array: (
  | { foo: true; bar: [number, number] }
  | { foo: false; bar: [number, number, number] }
)[] = [
  { foo: true, bar: [1, 2] },
  { foo: false, bar: [3, 4, 5] },
];
```

And I'd like to multiply all numbers in it by two. I want to do this:

```js
// Don't try to analyze this function, it's correct
export const mapTuple = <T extends unknown[], R>(
  array: T,
  callback: (value: T[number], index: number, array: T) => R,
): { [K in keyof T]: R } =>
  array.map(
    callback as (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => R,
  ) as { [K in keyof T]: R };

const result: typeof array = array.map(({ foo, bar }) => ({
  foo,
  bar: mapTuple(bar, (x) => x * 2),
}));
```

But, understandably, it produces a `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'`.

My current workaround is to use this silly ternary:

```js
const result: typeof array = array.map(({ foo, bar }) =>
  foo
    ? { foo, bar: mapTuple(bar, (x) => x * 2) }
    : { foo, bar: mapTuple(bar, (x) => x * 2) },
);
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: I don't think this is possible; the general problem is one of lack of support for "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The usual fix is a significant refactor as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) but I can't come up with a way to make it work.  I'd say either use your silly ternary or just use a type assertion and move on.  I could write that up as an answer but I doubt it's worth anyone's time.

Comment: Well, uh, I guess [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mp8oam) works, using the approach in ms/TS#47109, but at what cost?

Comment: Thank you for creating the playground snippet and pointing out the root cause! And thank you for putting all the work into documenting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not what your looking for since it uses casting but it's one way to do it.

```js
const result: typeof array = array.map(({ foo, bar }) =>
  ({ foo, bar: mapTuple(bar, (x) => x * 2) }) as (typeof array)[number]
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I'll go with, can't justify having runtime penalty.